# Transit visa to UK without going through control

Tags: visas, transit

My stepson (Jamaican) was refused to travel in transit through the UK to Germany. He holds a  visa to Germany and a US visa. Can you tell me if that was correct?

Comment: Was he flying from Jamaica? What type of German visa does he hold? Is he a resident there?

Answer (score 2):

According to the https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/jamaica/transit/no a Jamaican national normally would need an airport transit visa unless [you]

- are travelling to Australia, Canada, New Zealand or the USA and have a valid visa for that country
- are travelling from Australia, Canada, New Zealand or the USA and it’s less than 6 months since you last entered that country with a valid entry visa
- have a valid US permanent residence card issued on or after 21 April 1998 (or an I-797 extension letter issued by the Bureau of Citizenship if it’s expired)
- have a valid Canadian permanent resident card issued on or after 28 June 2002
- have a valid uniform format category D visa for entry to a state in the European Economic Area (EEA)
- have a valid uniform format residence permit issued by an EEA state

If none of the above scenarios apply to him, then the refusal was the correct course of action.

Answer (score 2):

Jamaican citizens do need a visa to transit in the UK, except if they qualify [for some exemption](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/jamaica/transit/no). The confusing thing is that US and German (Schengen) visitors visas are treated differently for this purpose.

Holders of regular US visitors visa qualify for an exemption when flying *to and from the US* but not between two other destinations. There are similar provisions for visitors to Canada, Australia and New Zealand *but not for short-stay German (Schengen) visa holders* so even though your stepson was flying to Germany with proper documentation that's not enough to qualify.

On the other hand, if your stepson is a *permanent resident* in the US or a resident in Germany then he should be able to transit without visa, even to travel between two other countries. This exemption from the direct airside transit visa requirement only applies to residents (i.e. holders of a long-stay visa or a residence permit) but not to visitors.

[A very detailed explanation of these rules is available on gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/275926/Charging_Guide_Jan_2014_Version_6.pdf)